# How can i add style for map marker

Tags: google-maps

I have Google maps and I would like to add a custom style for the icons.

With this code I can add custom a icon and define it's size:

```
icon: {
     url : '<? bloginfo('url'); ?>' + img_src  + '',
     scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(50,50)
},
```

But I would like to give the icon a white border, like the arrow below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbWKt.png]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: google map has id and select that id and specify img style.... but your markup if provided would be easy to answer.

Comment: I am almost convinced that icon image in the link was made on an image processing application (photoshop/gimp). If at all possible, I'd suggest using one of those to design your own pin style icon, and use that as the image for your marker.

Comment: So i canot add style css to icon ??

Comment: Well no, that is not completely true..you can add a marker as a symbol, and symbols take SVG paths - so technically you can style your images in the SVG (read more [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols)). But as far as adding custom images to icons you only have the following [options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon). Symbols would be a nice approach, but it's a learning curve - I'd definitely recommend you read into it though.

Comment: Hm..after going through the documentation myself I don't think Symbols would be the best option either. It looks like you can only specify SVG paths of vector elements in the Symbol object. However, what I think would work is maybe making an SVG from your image with the styling you want and using that as the custom image for your icon. Provided Google Maps supports SVGs for custom marker images - worth a try though.

Comment: So, How can i do that ??

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function to add custom icon

```
function setMarkers(map, markers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            zIndex: sites[3],
            html: sites[4]
        });
        var contentString = "Some content";
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            //alert(this.html);
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
        if(!firstOne) {
            firstOne = marker;
            marker.setIcon('theImages/hospBuilding.png');
        }
        else {
            marker.setIcon('theImages/hospitalIcon.png');
        }
    }           
}
```

Let me know if you need the entire script to display your own icon.

Comment: i can add custome icon but i need to add style for icon like css border ?? how can i do that